# Install Printers from XML Files

Tags: powershell

I backed up printers from a Windows 10 system to XML files.  I'm trying to add them using the Set-Printconfiguration CMDLET, but it seems to be not accepting variables?

I've looked everywhere but I cannot find anything saying my syntax is wrong.

```
#get list of printers in backup folder
$printerNames = (Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\printers\*.xml -Recurse | select name).name
    foreach ($printer in $printerNames)
        {
        Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $printer -PrintTicketXml c:\temp\printers\$printer
        }
```

Here is the code I used to get the printer XML files:

```
$TARGETDIR = "c:\temp\printers"
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR
}

# Get all the printers:
    $PN = (get-printer | select name).name

# Foreach loop to create XML file for each printer configuration
    Foreach ($P in $PN){
    $GPC = get-printconfiguration -PrinterName $P
    mkdir c:\temp\printers\$P 
    $GPC.PrintTicketXML | out-file C:\Temp\printers\$P.xml
# $p|select *|out-file -Path c:\temp\$p.xml -NoTypeInformation
    }
```

edit:  here is the error I'm getting:

```
Set-PrintConfiguration : The specified printer was not found.
At U:\PowerShell\Scripts\backup\newRestorePrinters.ps1:15 char:9
+         Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $printer -PrintTicketXml  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_PrinterConfiguration:ROOT/StandardCi...erConfiguration) [Set-PrintConfiguration], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070709,Set-PrintConfiguration
```

**edit**
I added more variables to get the list of printers w/out the *.XML* on the end of the names.  It still gives me the same error output.  It looks like it's not passing my variables to the *set-printconfiguration* command?

New restore script code:

```
$printerShortNameList = (Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\printers\*.xml -Recurse | select name).name
    foreach ($shortName in $printerShortNameList)
        {
        $shortName.Replace('.xml', "x")
        }

#get list of printers in backup folder
$printerNames = (Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\printers\*.xml -Recurse | select name).name
    foreach ($printer in $printerNames)
        {
        Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $shortName -PrintTicketXml c:\temp\printers\$printer
        }
```

Comment: Just stumbled upon this and a common Powershell misunderstanding jumped out at me. Where you are using Out-File, switch to Set-Content. The Out-* cmdlets go through the formatter, just like the output sent to the screen. Where among other things, the lines are wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

What was the error message?  Shouldn't you take the '.xml' off the end of $printer for the printer name?  I think you have to use add-printer first.  I don't believe Set-PrintConfiguration creates printers.

On the bottom when you make the xml files, why do you create the c:\temp\printers\$p directory?

Comment: Thanks - I added the output.  I think that may be it.  re-writing some of it now

Comment: i added the new code at the bottom of the post - seems like it's not passing my variables to the command?  maybe the syntax is off?

Answer (score 0):

[Set-PrintConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/set-printconfiguration?view=win10-ps):

> You need administrator credentials to use Set-PrintConfiguration.

Comment: i don't think so - i updated the post with the errors i'm getting - it's like it's not passing my variables to the command